# Sum of four dice is 20

Tags: probability, combinatorics, dice

Suppose we roll $4$ $6$-sided dice, what is the probability that their sum is equal to $20$ ?

Let $X_1,X_2,X_3,X_4$ denote the rolls' outcomes. I usually deal with this kind of question the same way : I use the law of total probability until reaching a sum of two-dice where I know by heart the possibilities. For example, if I am asked to find the probability that the sum of three $6-$sided die is $11$, then I do $$P(X_1+X_2+X_3=11)=\sum_{i=1}^6 P(X_2+X_3=11-i)P(X_1=i) = \frac 16 \sum_{i=1}^6 P(X_2+X_3=11-i) = \frac 16  P(5 \leq X_2+X_3 \leq 10)$$
$$= \frac 16 \frac{27}{36}=\frac{27}{6^3}$$

Here I do the same so : $$P(X_1+X_2+X_3+X_4=20)=\sum_{i=1}^6 P(X_2+X_3+X_4=20-i)P(X_1=i) $$ $$= \frac 16 \sum_{i=1}^6 P(X_2+X_3+X_4=20-i)$$ $$= \frac 16 \sum_{i=1}^6\sum_{j=1}^6 P(X_3+X_4=20-i-j)P(X_2=j) =\frac {1}{36}  P(8 \leq X_3+X_4 \leq 18)=\frac{15}{6^4}$$
which is not the right answer.

Can anyone explain what is the problem here ?

Comment: Another approach to counting the favorable cases is to use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle.

Comment: The problem is in the last line. Your sum on the LHS is adding up 36 terms, but the LHS, which gathers them together, looks like what you'd get from only adding together 11 terms. This is because there are 11 distinct possibilities for $i + j$, but the same value of $i + j$ can be made in multiple ways. So, for example, your sum will add $P(X_3 + X_4 = 10)$ three times, but the RHS only includes it once.

Comment: Sounds right, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have got a comment pointing out your mistake, and another suggesting the use of inclusion-exclusion.

I am giving  a simple stars and bars solution without inclusion-exclusion.

The mean total expected $= 3.5*4 = 14,$ and the distribution will be symmetrical around the mean, so number of outcomes will be the same for totals of $(14+6)= 20 $ and $(14-6)= 8$

And by stars and bars on the latter total, we directly get

# of otcomes = $\binom{7-1}{4-1} = 35$

and $Pr = \Large\frac{35}{6^4}$